# How to get a nested JSON object (array) in AWS IoT-Core and send it to AWS timestream as a string?

Tags: sql, windows-10-iot-core, amazon-timestream

I have the following payload (JSON) in my MQTT broker AWS IoT-Core / Topic (`+/+/myTopic`):

```
{
  "id":"sig3678",
  "r_timestmp":1659443813,
  "sku":61,
  "z_x_1":{
     "a_b":[ 234, 245, ...],
     "c_d":[ 435, -45, ...]
  },
  "z_x_2":{
     "a_b":[ -123, 245, ...],
     "c_d":[ 678, 245, ...]
  },
  "ad_xz3":657
}
```

I have a rule that save this payload to a `Timestream` table:

```
SELECT id AS id, r_timestamp AS r_timestamp,cast(get("z_x_1","a_b") as string) AS z_x_1_a_b FROM '+/+/myTopic'
```

As per the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-sql-json.html) I can't use `z_x_1.a_b` to get the object `[ 234, 245, ...]`. Also I want to save a string from this object then I need to convert this object into a string using `cast()` function from this [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-sql-functions.html#iot-sql-function-cast).

Inside the rule I have the following:
Dimensions:
name: z_x_1_a_b, value ${z_x_1_a_b}

And in CloudWatch I am getting the followin error:

```
"failures": [
        {
            "failedAction": "TimestreamAction",
            "failedResource": "sig3678#z_x_1_a_b",
            "errorMessage": "Failed to write records to Timestream. The error received was 'Errors at dimensions.1: [Dimension value can not be empty.], Errors at measures.2: [Measure value is empty.]'. Message arrived on +/+/myTopic, Action: timestream, Database: sig3678, Table: z_x_1_a_b"
        }
    ]
```

The desired output should be:

```
{
  id:'sig3678',
  r_timestamp:1659443813,
  z_x_1_a_b: '[ 234, 245, ...]'
}
```

ready to be inserted in the table `z_x_1_a_b`. It seems that `z_x_1_a_b` is comming empty `[Dimension value can not be empty.]`. Maybe some issue with the way I am filtering the topic?!

What am I missing?

Comment: Have to tried republishing the iot rule data to a new topic? Validate if the data is coming as expected after using "select ..." clause

Comment: Have you figured a way to do that?